# Drop images into div and total sum

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a drag and drop of images in a div and sum the value of each image. I am getting the value from the alt attribute from each image. The script doubles the value of the image instead of adding each value.

```
     function allowDrop(bet) {
        bet.preventDefault();
    }
 
    function drag(bet) {
        bet.dataTransfer.setData("text", bet.target.id);
    }
 
   function drop(bet) {
            bet.preventDefault();
            var fetchData = bet.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            bet.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(fetchData).cloneNode(true));

            // Get all the images
            let images = document.getElementById("circle").getElementsByTagName('img');

            let sum = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                let altValue = parseInt(images[i].alt);
                if (!isNaN(altValue)) {
                    sum += altValue;
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
        }

    <div id="circle"
         ondrop="drop(event)"
         ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      </div>
    <br>
<input id="total" type="number" value="0"/>    
    <img class="chips" id="a100"
         src="images/Chips/100chip-64.svg"
        alt="100"
         draggable="true"
         ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <img class="chips" id="a5"
         src="images/Chips/5chip-64.svg"
            alt="5"
         draggable="true"
         ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

Comment: Please clarify what the issue at hand is? What specific error do you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're appending the cloned image element.
Try modifying the code a bit:

```
function drop(bet) {
    bet.preventDefault();
    var fetchData = bet.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var draggedImage = document.getElementById(fetchData);

    // Create a new image element and set its attributes from the dragged image
    var newImage = document.createElement("img");
    newImage.setAttribute("src", draggedImage.src);
    newImage.setAttribute("alt", draggedImage.alt);
    newImage.setAttribute("draggable", draggedImage.draggable);
    newImage.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
    newImage.className = "chips";

    bet.target.appendChild(newImage);

    // Get all the images
    let images = document.getElementById("circle").getElementsByTagName('img');

    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        let altValue = parseInt(images[i].alt);
        if (!isNaN(altValue)) {
            sum += altValue;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
}
```

Comment: It is not adding the images correctly. It doubles the value, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, etc..

Comment: Could you share the image/html code too?

Comment: As requested, I edited the post to include the entire code.

Comment: Modified the code in answer. Could you try?